# How to use a field block in many Wordpress Pages with Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am building an eCommerce site using Wordpress and Woocommerce and hit a roadblock and don't see how to solve.

I am using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) to create a block of content that I want to reuse in many different pages. The problem is, when you create the field block, you have to choose where do you want to display this. My thought was, let's display it in the Admin section of the Home Page, which will be the only place where the admin will be able to manipulate this content.

Then my thought process was to create a partial in the code (not the admin, of course) and then call this partial from all the pages I wanted to display this content.

The problem is, the content displays in the Home Page, but anywhere else I only get the empty HTML tags without the content.

My partial:

content-footer-callouts.php

```
<?php  

// FOOTER CALLOUTS
// ---------------

// Left
$left_callout_image              = get_field('left_callout_image');
$left_callout_title              = get_field('left_callout_title');
$left_callout_description        = get_field('left_callout_description');

// Center
$center_callout_title            = get_field('center_callout_title');
$center_callout_description      = get_field('center_callout_description');

// Right
$right_callout_image             = get_field('right_callout_image');
$right_callout_title             = get_field('right_callout_title');
$right_callout_description       = get_field('right_callout_description');

?>


<div class="row">

    <div class="gives-back section phone-12 laptop-4 columns">

        <img src="<?php echo $left_callout_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $left_callout_image['alt']; ?>">

        <h3><?php echo $left_callout_title; ?></h3>

        <?php echo $left_callout_description; ?>

    </div><!-- .gives-back -->


    <div class="social section phone-12 laptop-4 columns">

        <ul class="social-links">

            <?php  

                $social_footer_args = array(
                    'post_type'      => 'social',
                    'order_by'       => 'post_id',
                    'order'          => 'ASC',
                    'posts_per_page' => '4'
                );

                $social_icons = new WP_Query($social_footer_args);

            ?>

            <?php while ($social_icons -> have_posts()) : $social_icons -> the_post(); ?>

                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_field('social_url'); ?>" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-<?php the_field('social_icon'); ?> fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </ul><!-- #social-links -->

        <h3><?php echo $center_callout_title; ?></h3>

        <?php echo $center_callout_description; ?>                
    </div><!-- .social -->


    <div class="purchase section phone-12 laptop-4 columns">

        <img src="<?php echo $right_callout_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $right_callout_image['alt']; ?>">

        <h3><?php echo $right_callout_title; ?></h3>

        <?php echo $right_callout_description; ?>

    </div><!-- .purchase -->

</div><!-- .row -->
```

My call from any page:

```
<section class="engage row-full padded-section">

    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'footer-callouts'); ?>

</section><!-- .engage .row-full -->
```

A screenshot from the ACF interface:

[image]

Comment: Add the post ID of your "Home" page as the second parameter to your get_field() calls. That should solve your little issue. See the documenation for more info: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: Dude, thanks a lot. If you want write that same thing as a response instead of a comment so I can Accept the answer and vote up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the post ID of your "Home" page as the second parameter to your get_field() calls.

```
// Your home page post ID
$post_id = 1;

// Your get_field() calls should look like the one below
$field_var = get_field( 'meta_key', $post_id );
```

See the documenation for more info: http://advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field

You should also use proper sanitation functions before output. Check out the link below to find WordPress core sanitation functions. Try to be as strict as needed.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Output_Sanitation